# Angular service array empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-services

I am trying to store JSON's data in a shared array within a service. The problem is that every time I want to update the service's array with some new content (e.g. new JSON), I need to first clear the array and after that the array remains empty, instead of loading new data.

My service looks like this:

```
.service('jsonTest',
    function() {
      var json = [];

      function storeJson(file) {
        json=[];
        json.push(file);
      }
      return {
        storeJson: storeJson,
        showJson: json
      }
    });
```

As you can see, I am cleaning the array each time before loading new data with

```
json = [];
```

But then it still remains empty after loading new stuff.

What am I doing wrong here?

You can check that example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/tN9WvNminw1uLpThWPvu?p=preview
The service is in app.js and is being used in MainCtrl (main.js) and ProductCtrl (product.js).

Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not watching json and updating showJson each time it's changed. You need to do something like:

```
.service('jsonTest', function() {
  var json = {
    showJson: [],
    storeJson: function(file) {
      json.showJson=[];
      json.showJson.push(file);
    }
  };

  return json;
});
```

Because `json` is a local variable, when you set it equal to `[]` inside `storeJson`, it's using a new memory location, i.e. it's not a reference variable, so `showJson` is not automatically updated. If you were clearing the existing array (maybe by `.pop` until there are no elements left), it would work, but since you're assigning a *new* empty array, it doesn't.

Alternatively, you could also make `showJson` a function that returns `json`. That would also work.

```
.service('jsonTest', function() {
  var json = [];

  function storeJson(file) {
    json=[];
    json.push(file);
  }
  function showJson() {
    return json;
  }
  return {
    storeJson: storeJson,
    showJson: showJson
  }
});
```

Comment: Now I see where the issue was ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i think you should be using an empty object rather than an array.

```
.service('jsonTest', function() {
    var json = {};
    return {
        set: function(val){
            json = val;
        },
        get: function(){
            return json;
        }
    };
});
```

Updated you're [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AYwn7pnojPsAOEd6R55f?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, a better structure is to move $http calls to service itself, so its truly a service. Tben inject the service into MainCtrl.

So, you can invoke service (lets call it 'myAppService') like:

```
 .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'myAppService',
    function ($scope, $log, myAppService) {

       $scope.getData = function(filepath) {
          // do something with results ie. store etc.
          var fileOrPromise = myAppService.get(filepath);
       };
 ]);
```

and a service/factory:

```
 .factory('myAppService', ['$http', '$q', '$window',
    function($http, $q, $window) {
      return {
          get: function(filepath) {
             return _goGetFile(filepath);
          },
          // do something else
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Here is some references to design and best practices:

1. [johnpapa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)
2. [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure)

Hope this helps.